# unable to access aws instance through ssh

Tags: amazon-ec2

Whenever I try to access AWS instance by using ssh I the following error:

> Connection blocked because server only allows public key authentication. Please contact your network administrator.
>
> Connection to ec2-54-214-97-39.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com closed by remote
> host.
>
> Connection to ec2-54-214-97-39.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
> closed.

I am accessing by ssh enabled command prompt:

```
chmod 400 virtue.pem
ssh -i "file.pem" ubuntu@ec2-publicIp.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I am unable to access aws instance vitual machine .

The error is like the one mentioned here:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/ssh-key-no-longer-working

Comment: Add verbose output to your ssh command so we can see further info. -vvv

Comment: Add the VM configuration.

Comment: Have you _ever_ been able to ssh into this instance? Did you just launch this as a new instance from an AMI (if so which one)? Why is your `ssh` command referring to `file.pem` when you did a `chmod` on `virtue.pem`? You should use `ssh -i virtue.pem ...`

Comment: i am using  virtue.pem in place  of file.pem

Comment: yes, i used  to access same way , i am trying to access now,but,suddenly ,get that error ,unable to access aws instance :(

Comment: when i tried to repeat same steps using different broadband ,i am able to access it :), i think some port block by internet provider in my office

Answer (score 0):

You need confirm that file.pem is the correct key to access to the instances, and use chmod 400 to give permissions to the .pem in your computer. you can view the logs in the AWS console to verify if there is any message about ssh access.
You can launch other instance with other .pem or detach root volume and attach to other instance to validate the config files

Comment: i am using virtue.pem in place of file.pem

Comment: you need use ssh -i "virtue.pem" ubuntu@ec2-publicIp.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com. virtue.pem is the key name that AWS console Shows in the instance description ?

Comment: I am doing same way ,you typed above but still got above error

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem caused by (man-in-the-middle attack).
Change your network to a private one and retry!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).